# Page visibility API - check if browser is in background?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/,

> On getting, the hidden attribute MUST return true if the Document contained by the top level browsing context (root window in the browser's viewport) [HTML5] is not visible at all. The attribute MUST return false if the Document contained by the top level browsing context is at least partially visible on at least one screen.

However, using the following script:

```
setInterval(function() {console.log(document.hidden);}, 1000)
```

it keeps printing `false` when the browser is running in the background, i.e. not visible at all. It does print `true` if I switch to a different tab, or minimize the browser, however.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, it sounds like a bad implementation of the browser...
Does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: @matan7890: I verified this on Win7 with Chrome 45, IE11 and FF38. They all print `false` although the browser is not minimized, but in background, i.e. completely hidden by other windows. If browser is minimized or a different tab is active, it prints `true` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

PageVisibility API returns true only if the API is completely hidden. If your window is in the background, but even partially visible, it will return false.

Try putting it in the background, making it smaller than another window, then placing that window overtop. It now returns true.

You may want something like document.hasFocus instead (or some combination).

Comment: Nope, its still printing false when I make the browser small. I need it to stop rendering 3d content so hasFocus isn't what I need.

Comment: You made the browser small and completely covered it with another window? What browser are you using?

Comment: @mofojed: see my comment on the question. It does this on Windows for all major browsers.